# how to reduce $(1-\alpha)^{T-i}$ into a sum

Tags: abstract-algebra, combinatorics, polynomials, binomial-coefficients, multinomial-coefficients

I'm given the following proof:

\begin{align}
& \sum^T_{i=k} \alpha^i(1-\alpha)^{T-i} \binom{T}{i}
\\&=\sum^T_{i=k} \alpha^i \binom{T}{i} \sum_{j=0}^{T-i}(-\alpha)^j\binom{T-i}{j}
\\&=\alpha^k \sum^{T-k}_{i=0} \frac{T!i!}{(T-k)!(i+k)!} \sum^{T-k-i}_{j=0} \alpha^i (-\alpha)^j \frac{(T-k)!}{i!j!(T-k-i-j)!}
\end{align}

I would like to know how 
$$(1-\alpha)^{T-i}$$ 
turned into
$$\sum_{j=0}^{T-i}(-\alpha)^j\binom{T-i}{j}$$
and the rules used to turn second line to third line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [binomial theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_theorem)

$$
(x + y)^n = \sum_{k=0}^n {n\choose k} x^{n-k} y^{k}
$$

In your case just make $x = 1$, $y = -\alpha$ and $n = T-i$:

$$
(1 -\alpha)^{T-i} = \sum_{k=0}^{T-i} {T-i\choose k} (-\alpha)^{k}
$$

Comment: Ah stupid me. Thanks!

Comment: @MoneyBall Just call $i \to i - k$ and expand the binomial coefficients

Comment: yep turns out it's just algebraic manipulation. Thank you so much!